# Finding month and year of the maximum and minimum values in a excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of the rentability of a investment fund through 2022 and 2023.

[image]

I'm trying to write a formula that will give me a date (in format mm/YY) of the maximum and minimum values of the lines "Fundo". The year is a merged cell on the left and the months are a row on top of the tables.

Edit: I only want the date of the maximum and minimum overall (from 06/2022 to 06/2023).

Thanks in advance

Edit 2: Here's the table. Sorry for not posting it early.

|  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Jan | Fev | Mar | Abr | Mai | Jun | Jul | Ago | Set | Out | Nov | Dez | Ano |
| 2023 | Fundo | -6,51% | -4,70% | -7,33% | -4,95% | -5,88% | -4,45% |  |  |  |  |  |  | -29,43% |
|  | %CDI | -579,59% | -512,37% | -623,71% | -539,61% | ######## | -624,48% |  |  |  |  |  |  | -595,48% |
|  | CDI | 1,12% | 0,92% | 1,17% | 0,92% | 0,71% | 0,71% |  |  |  |  |  |  | 4,94% |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2022 | Fundo |  |  |  |  |  | -4,23% | -10,61% | -15,81% | -11,71% | -9,38% | -9,54% | -7,76% | -51,89% |
|  | %CDI |  |  |  |  |  | #DIV/0! | #DIV/0! | #DIV/0! | -2301,19% | -918,52% | ######## | ######## | -1393,60% |
|  | CDI |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0,51% | 1,02% | 1,02% | 1,12% | 3,72% |

Could you redo the answer with this data? The previous formula isn't working on my table. I think it's because my excel uses ";" as separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula gets the month and year in format mm/yy (also in case of duplicates, as in example below):

```
=LET(fundo, VSTACK(C4:N4,C8:N8),
     max,   IF(fundo=MAX(fundo),1,NA()),
TEXT(TOCOL(REPT(C2:N2,max),3),"00")&"-"&RIGHT(TOCOL(REPT(VSTACK(A4,A8),max),3),2))
```

This takes all values of 2022 and 2023 and returns the header(s) and year(s) if it matches the max value.

[image]

And for edited version:

```
=LET(fundo, VSTACK(C3:N3,C6:N6), 
     max,   IF(fundo=MAX(fundo),1,NA()),
TEXT(TOCOL(REPT(C1:N1,max),3),"00")&"-"&RIGHT(TOCOL(REPT(VSTACK(A3,A6),max),3),2))
```

[image]

Comment: hey @P.b could you take a look at the edit that i've posted? I'm not able to use this formula for some reason

Comment: Check my edit. If it doesn't work, make sure number values are not text.

Comment: You may need to use `;` as a separator (judging by the decimals separator being `,` ) : `=LET(fundo;VSTACK(C3:N3;C6:N6);max;IF(fundo=MAX(fundo);1;NA());TEXT(TOCOL(REPT(C1:N1;max);3);"00")&"-"&RIGHT(TOCOL(REPT(VSTACK(A3;A6);max);3);2))`

Comment: Another reason why you should always post your own attempt(s). That way we would recognize correct range and separator.

Comment: Glad to help. So was it the `;` separator?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    =LET(A,IFERROR(MATCH(Max([Fundo cells 2023]),[Fundo cells 2023],0),0),
         B,IFERROR(MATCH(Max([Fundo cells 2022]),[Fundo cells 2022],0),0),
         DATE(IF(A>0,2023,2022),MAX(A,B),1))
```